# Alter text in textarea/input field without loosing ability to undo (as of end 2023)

Tags: javascript

*This has been asked many times and every answer is using now outdated (aka no longer working) or deprecated (aka may still work but might stop working at any time) APIs.*

**As of end of 2023 how do we alter text in textarea/input/editable elements without losing undo/redo capability? (without going through *bs* hoops of creating our own undo/redo implementation)**

Here are 3 different approaches that has been suggested as answers, plus an extra one with my attempt of implementing a custom undo buffer:

- `_simple()` - simple replacing textarea value - clears undo buffer
- `_execCommand()` - works fine, but [`execCommand`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/execCommand) is
  deprecated
- `_textEvent()` - doesn't work at all due to
  "untrusted" events are ignored
- `_simpleCustom()` - same as `_simple()`, but it uses custom undo buffer, it's far from perfect, only tested in one OS/browser.

```js
function _simple(el = textarea)
{
  const data = getData(el);
  el.value = data.textStart + data.textInsert + data.textEnd;
  el.selectionStart = data.start + data.textInsert.length;
  el.selectionEnd = el.selectionStart;
}

function _execCommand()
{
  const data = getData(textarea);
  document.execCommand("insertText", null, data.textInsert);
}

function _textEvent()
{
  const data = getData(textarea);
  const event = document.createEvent('TextEvent');
  event.initTextEvent('textInput', true, true, null, data.textInsert);
  textarea.dispatchEvent(event);
}

function getData(el)
{
  el.focus();
  return {
    start: el.selectionStart,
    end: el.selectionEnd,
    textStart: el.value.slice(0, el.selectionStart),
    textEnd: el.value.slice(el.selectionEnd),
    textInsert: "" + ~~(Math.random() * 10)
  }
}


const _simpleCustom = (el =>
{
  const getState = () => ({
    value: el.value,
    start: el.selectionStart,
    end: el.selectionEnd
  });
  const undoBuffer = [getState()];
  const undoAdd = () =>
  {
    undoBuffer[++undoIndex] = getState();
    undoBuffer.length = undoIndex + 1; //make sure this is a last item in the array
  };
  const updateValue = data =>
  {
    el.value = data.value;
    el.selectionStart = data.start;
    el.selectionEnd = data.end;
  }
  let undoIndex = 0;

  el.addEventListener("input", undoAdd);
  el.addEventListener("keydown", evt =>
  {
    if (!evt.altKey && !evt.shiftKey && evt.ctrlKey && (evt.code === "KeyZ" || evt.code === "KeyY"))
    {
      evt.preventDefault();
      undoIndex += evt.code === "KeyZ" ? -1 : 1

      if (undoIndex >= undoBuffer.length)
        undoIndex = undoBuffer.length - 1;

      if (undoIndex < 0)
        undoIndex = 0;

      const data = undoBuffer[undoIndex];
      if (data)
        updateValue(data);

    }
  });
  return () => 
  {
    _simple(el);
    undoAdd();
  }
})(textarea2);
```

```html
<ol>
  <li>type some text</li>
  <li>click a button</li>
  <li>press CTRL+Z (undo)</li>
</ol>
<textarea id="textarea"></textarea>
<br>
<button onclick="_simple()">_simple()</button>
<button onclick="_execCommand()">_execCommand()</button>
<button onclick="_textEvent()">_textEvent()</button>
<br>
<br>
<textarea id="textarea2"></textarea>
<br>
<button onclick="_simpleCustom()">_simpleCustom()</button>
```